# Are History.SE's moderators paid for their contribution?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Are History.SE's moderators paid for their contribution?

Coz, apparently, it requires a great amount of time reviewing the posts.

Comment: No - we are volunteers; note that most users with privilege can review posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this was a serious question...

No, the moderators on this site are elected volunteers.

There are some StackExchange employees around who can act as moderators, but they are generally more like roving troubleshooters. You aren't likely to see them interact with History.SE much, unless they happen to take an interest in a topic that got brought up.

There are some occasional *perks*. There was one year under the previous ownership where they sent all of us ballcaps with a blue diamond on them. That was nice. Nobody knows what the heck it means when I wear it, but I guess I know. A lot of years they let us vote on which charities SE will donate to. It doesn't sound like much, but that means a surprising amount to me, because I believe strongly in some of the choices they offer.

As for the level of work, well there were a few years there I was doing this alone, and making all the mistakes, and *that* was work. With a full mod team, its basically as much work as you want to put in it. You may have noticed I'm a bit of a loudmouth online here, but honestly everyone else is so good at handling flags that I hardly ever get the chance to take care of one anymore.

Still, there are at least of couple of us who do a decent amount of post editing (which users with enough privs can do too, hint hint). Editing is like a real job that people (eg: my Mom) get paid actual money to do, so from that standpoint its a bit nuts. But again, that's not just a mod responsibility. Any user with enough rep can help improve the site that way.